# How can I improve these two assembly questions so they get a better reception?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

[How to read bit ranges in a register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421309/how-to-read-bit-ranges-in-a-register)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66733227/how-to-work-out-a-algorithm-for-score-reel-emulation ([link to screenshot](https://cln.sh/oRDW1t) for <10k users)

Comment: You don't say which assembly language. Also, there's no attempt at a solution so we don't know where you're stuck. They are really just statements of requirements and those tend not to fare very well as many people object to them as a request to do your work for you.

Comment: The 'bit ranges' question is 'Computers 101' boolean algebra.  I remain to be convinced that SO should be teaching basics OR that a duplicate does not exist.

Comment: AND Googling the title prepended by 'assembler' AND/OR 'C' generates useful links.

Answer (score 11):

This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66733227/how-to-work-out-a-algorithm-for-score-reel-emulation is not a question.

It is an collection of post-it notes cobbled together that might or might not be relevant to the actual algorithm you're looking to solve. We and future visitors are less interested in your thought process, only the final outcome matters.

It is unclear what you expect as an answer. Some text? A design? Pseudo code? Z80 assembly? 6502?

It is unclear what you already have going with that algorithm.

Did you try to find any existing solution to that algorithm? If yes, it is best to include summarize that. If not, why?

The question is unclear to me.

This question [How to read bit ranges into a register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421309/how-to-read-bit-ranges-into-a-register) would be much more clear if it had  (pseudo) code and maybe what assembly you expect. I can't judge the answer but it doesn't look like assembly but some high-level language, yet you accepted the answer.

Were you looking for assembly language or just a general idea to solve the problem you faced?

All in all that is a bit unclear which is a reason to downvote.

Comment: I just fixed number 2

Comment: @BenMadison it didn't improve much but I gave it another edit to fix grammar and spelling and some layout.